# Return a list from a data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table

How can I return a `list` from a `data.table`? The problem is that whenever I return a `list` in the `j` part it is transformed into a `data.table`format by design?

Assume that I want to return a `list` whose elements are named(!) length 1 vectors, i.e.:

```r
expected_result <- list(A = c(a = 1), B = c(b = 2), C = c(c = 3))
```

This does the trick, but it feels hackish with the 2 lists just to extract then again the first element.

So what would be the canonical way?

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

d <- data.table(id = LETTERS[1:3],
                nm = letters[1:3],
                val = 1:3)

d[, .(.(setNames(val, nm) %>%
           split(seq_along(.)) %>%
           setNames(id)))]$V1[[1]] %>%
   all.equal(expected_result)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

### Edit

@akrun gave a nice non `data.table` solution, but I would rather find a solution which uses `[.data.table` syntax.

Comment: One problem you're going to have is you want a `list`. Whenever `data.table` sees the `j` return a compatible `list`, it will automatically convert it back into a `data.table`. While I understand your desire to remain completely within the `data.table` methods for most operations, one of the appealing advantages to the package (in-place operations) is not possible with custom transformations like this. I suggest that akrun's first `with(d,...)` solution is compact, elegant, and about as good as you'll get given this structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be using `with`.  `split` the named vector created (with 'val', and 'nm' columns) with 'id'

```
with(d, split(setNames(val, nm), id))
```

-output

```
#$A
#a 
#1 

#$B
#b 
#2 

#$C
#c 
#3
```

---

Or if we want to use create the `list` within `data.table`, it is a bit convoluted as `data.table`/`data.frame` columns are `list` elements with equal length.  So, we may need to `unclass` the attributes or wrap it in a nested `list` and then `flatten` the `list` elements

```
do.call(c, d[, .(list(split(setNames(val, nm), id)))]$V1)
#$A
#a 
#1 

#$B
#b 
#2 

#$C
#c 
#3
```

Comment: True, but this deliberately avoids `data.table` syntax. I will edit my question to make clear that it should be done in `data.table` syntax.